# compare two string variables in php one obtained from array other from user

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel-5

I need to compare two string variables one is obtained from the object array by looping and the other by the user.

When the user inputs : Sam,ABC

```
$in = $request->input('name');
```

this input is taken, and string "ABC" is stored in another variable.

```
$u_in = explode(",", $in);
$user_dept = $u_in[1];
```

Now $user_dept has string "ABC".
Object array `$users` is fetched from the database, where under dept column the department to be compared is stored.

```
foreach ($users as $p => $val ) {
$c = $val->dept;
  if(strcasecmp($user_dept,$c) == 0 ){
    echo "yes";
  } else{
    echo "no";
  }
}
```

But here, the comparison always returns "no" even when the string is same.
The aim is to match the dept of the users.
What is the correct code to be used ?

Comment: is $dept= $user_dept?

Comment: yes, I have done the change

Comment: is $c = $val->dept= "abc" or "ABC" coz strcasecmp is working fine in my comp ..just echo $val

Comment: when I do echo $val it throws this error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: $c can be both "abc" or "ABC"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
foreach ($users as $p => $val ) {
$c = strtolower($val->dept);
$user_dept = strtolower($user_dept);
  if($user_dept == $c){
    echo "yes";
  } else{
    echo "no";
  }
}
```